# Excel linked picture of a pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've not been able to find an answer to my question through searching the internet, so I'm asking here.

I am able to paste a linked picture within my workbook, however my problem lies when my pivot table is larger than the area I delimited, the excess information is not shown.

Can linked pictures be resized depending on their linked contents?

Thanks for your help.
The picture below shows my problem. The top portion is showing the clipped table.

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to [Camera](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2106-excel-camera-tool.html) in Excel?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot or more clarification on what your problem is? A linked image should always show the entire pivot table area, you can squish it down and distort it, but it doesn't hide columns.

Comment: No, when you copy a range and special paste it as a linked picture.

Comment: @QHarr - Woah, I never knew about the camera. That's pretty neat!

Comment: @Mako212, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Camera if you set the source formula correctly can [resize](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/881706-need-to-make-camera-tool-image-dynamic-auto-resize-as-data-is-added-deleted.html) but not fast.

Comment: @BruceWayne i have rarely used it as can easily distort and become hard to read (though may be ways around this) but there are times when it is handy and updates automatically so nice.